# Ajax.Request always returns failure on IE

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

```
function voip_submit()
{
  var link = encodeURIComponent('/goform/az_ifx_set_voip_sip_linebasicaccount'); 
  var loc = 'page=quickstart.asp';
  loc += '&status='+document.az_sip.status.value;
  loc += '&cvflag='+document.az_sip.cvflag.value;
  loc += '&vlstatus1='+document.az_sip.vlstatus1.value;
  loc += '&vlstatus2='+document.az_sip.vlstatus2.value;
  var retVal =  new Ajax.Request(link, {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: loc,
      encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
        submit_voip1();
      },
      onFailure: function(transport) {
            Tiny.hide();
            showAlert("Apply settings failed");
      }       
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no need to store the new Ajax.Request object in `retVal`. The `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks are the ones that actually handle the data (or lack thereof) "returned" by the request.

Secondly, you should use the built-in Prototype methods for encoding the data

```
function voip_submit()
{
    new Ajax.Request('/goform/az_ifx_set_voip_sip_linebasicaccount', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {
            page:      'quickstart.asp',
            status:    document.az_sip.status.value,
            cvflag:    document.az_sip.cvflag.value,
            vlstatus1: document.az_sip.vlstatus1.value,
            vlstatus2: document.az_sip.vlstatus2.value
        },
        encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            submit_voip1();
        },
        onFailure: function(transport) {
            Tiny.hide();
            showAlert("Apply settings failed");
        }       
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Flambino Thanks for your answer. I have resolved this issue the problem in not in the Ajax Request. Its on the server side which is not sending the code 200 Ok. Looks like IE is very specific on the HTTP return codes.